# How do I remove this graphical error for this button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am new to web development and I have a bug that I cannot seem to fix. Basically, I have a button that highlights when its hovered and it works but there is a small outline of the original color when hovered. I'm pretty sure this is not because of an outline or a border. The bug is displayed in the picture provided. Here is the code:

```css
body {
    background-color: #2d2f31;
}

.start{
    width: 200px;
    height: 75px;
    border: none;
    color:black;
    background-color: beige;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(36, 36, 37);
    font-size: 15px;
    outline: 0;
    transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.start:hover{
    box-shadow: inset 200px 0 0 0 rgb(36, 36, 37);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class=buttondiv>
        <button onclick="coming('maintext', '#F0F');" class='start' >button</button>
 </div>
```

[image]

EDIT: I'm using Google Chrome and Windows 11 (idk if OS is important)

Comment: I'd say the blinking behaviour in Chrome is worse than having an outline

Answer (score 3):

The box shadow is slightly transparent around those corners, allowing you to see the beige background color underneath. Changing the background color of the button on hover to the same color as the box shadow fixes this. The effect is ever so slightly different, but I can't really tell just from looking at it.

Also, on chrome, this box shadow transition blinks. I messed around with it and changed the 4th number to 1px and it stopped blinking. I couldn't tell you why, but there you go.

```
.start:hover{
    background: rgb(36, 36, 37);
    box-shadow: inset 200px 0 0 1px rgb(36, 36, 37);
    color: white;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #2d2f31;
}

.start{
    width: 200px;
    height: 75px;
    border: none;
    color:black;
    background-color: beige;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(36, 36, 37);
    font-size: 15px;
    outline: 0;
    transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.start:hover{
    background: rgb(36, 36, 37);
    box-shadow: inset 200px 0 0 1px rgb(36, 36, 37);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class=buttondiv>
        <button onclick="coming('maintext', '#F0F');" class='start' >button</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: The visual bug is still there during the 0.5s transition. I though adding `transition-property: color, box-shadow;`, `transition-duration: 0.5s;` and  `transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);` would fix this, as then the transition would only affect `box-shadow` and `color`. It only worked half the time and when it did work, it broke the animation. No idea why.

Answer (score 1):

I just got why it's like that. It's cause of your "beige" background. When I change it to "red" look how it is

red background button

Fix: Let's give background when :hover state is used

So your code will be like

```
.start:hover{
    box-shadow: inset 200px 0 0 0 rgb(36, 36, 37);
    color: white;
    background: rgb(36,36,37);
    }
```

Let me know how it is

Comment: Thanks! It works, but now there is another similar problem. It worked for the final state, but for the transition state, the problem is still there. What I mean is after the animation is finished, there is no outline. But during the duration of the transition, the border is still there